# Why do I have local merge commits in a repository that is only pulling?

Tags: git

I have a shared development server which is set up to automatically *pull the latest version* of a git repository every minute.

From time to time, this appears to fail, and when checking with `git status` I get a message that

```
Your branch is ahead of <branch> by <X> commits.
```

If I follow up by `git log` I see this kind of entries that are not in the remote, and where the author is `root`:

```
commit [...]
Merge: [...] [...]
Author: root <root@ip-[...]>
Date:   Mon Feb 26 15:51:06 2018 +0000
  Merge branch '<branch>' of github.com:[...]/[...] into <branch>
```

How is this possible?

I am the only one with `ssh` access to this server, and the only `git` commands this server is executing are the following:

```
clean, reset, checkout, fetch, pull
```

Other things I'm doing on the server is *changing permissions* on the repository files after a pull.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the server you're pulling from ever perform a git reset? When messing with history it can make pulls do weird things.

Comment: @Wazner, as mentioned I do `git reset` in some cases *on the server that is pulling from github*. Any idea how that would create a merge commit?

Comment: As long as you reset to a commit previous in the history, that should not create a merge commit. Merge commits are created when you pull and your repository contains commits that the server does not. This can happen when the repository you're pulling from resets to a commit before other commits you've already pulled.

Comment: If the previous comment is the problem. I would recommend not using pull, and instead just fetch and reset to the remote branch.

Comment: What I learned was that `git pull` may cause local merges, which can be prevented by either substituting for `git fetch` and `git checkout`or `git reset`, or by using the `--mirror` option when cloning. I will experiment and find the solution that suits me best. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I conclude that it's either a side effect of some of your `git reset`s, or a result of someone manipulating history in the upstream repository in a way that you're not expecting.  (That is, they—whoever "they" are—are "rewriting history" as some call it.)

If that's the case, using rebase instead of merge *may* help.  (But see the caveats below.)  And, if you never intend to have any commits of your own in this repository, using a mirror, or otherwise making your repo-B a "perfect copy" of repo-A, may be better than either, although this gets a bit tricky.

#### Long

If I understand correctly, the situation is that there are two repositories involved:

- Repository A (at `ssh://github.com/some/path/...` though you spell this `github.com:some/path/...`) is something you have no control over, and unknown things occur there.
- Repository B is your own repository on your own machine.

In repository B, you use the commands:

- `git clean`
- `git reset`
- `git checkout`
- `git fetch`
- `git pull`
- `chmod`

and at some point(s) in time you find that `git pull`—which runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge`—has created merge commits in repository B (which have no corresponding commit in repository A, i.e., these merge commits exist only in B).

Since the only one of those commands that will create merges is `git merge` (the one run by `git pull`), we can—if this set of facts is accurate—conclude that it is in fact the `git merge` run by `git pull` that creates them.  This fits well with the log message:

```
Merge branch '<branch>' of github.com:[...]/[...] into <branch>
```

which is what `git pull` sets up as the default merge message (so that if you don't edit it, that's the message you get) when `git pull` runs `git merge`.

Your question, I assume, is: why do these merges occur?  They occur for the same reason that any merge occurs: you tell Git to merge with a commit when one of several conditions is met.  These conditions vary a bit depending on the options you give to `git merge` (through `git pull` in this cases; note that you can configure alternative defaults for of these through `git config`, but I'll assume you have not done that either):

- `--ff`: do a fast-forward merge if possible, otherwise do a real merge
- `--no-ff`: force a merge even if a fast-forward merge is possible
- `--ff-only`: do a fast-forward merge if possible, and if not, exit with error instead of creating a real merge

We can conclude that you're not using `--ff-only`, since that would mean you would not get a local merge commit.  I will assume you are not using `--no-ff` since that would mean that you would get forced merges quite commonly.  That leaves either `--ff`, or no options at all, which will (depending on `git config` settings) default to `--ff`: fast-forward if possible, else do real merge.

#### Merge: can it fast-forward?

So, let's consider the cases where Git will fast-forward, and the cases where Git will do a real merge.  To get Git to do one of these—at Git's discretion—you would use the two-command sequence:

```
git checkout <something>
git merge <other>
```

where the `<something>` is typically a branch name (and the `git checkout` itself can be arbitrarily far back in time, and have other Git commands come after it, as long as they are not `git checkout` and therefore don't change the branch name to which the `git checkout` attaches your Repo-B `HEAD`).  The `<other>` in `git merge` is anything that identifies some other commit.  When `git pull` runs `git merge`, the `<other>` is a hash ID as obtained from Repo-A during the `git fetch` step.

Your Git then looks into your repository to find:

- your current commit (`HEAD`)
- the other commit (from the argument)
- the commit graph, constructed from the data stored in these two (unchangeable, read-only) commits—or at least, enough of the commit graph to locate the *merge base*.

The commit graph is something we can draw ourselves, or have `git log --graph` draw for us.  Actual graphs tend to be pretty tangled, but for illustration we can use nice simple ones.  I'll draw a graph with six commits shown, and labeled with individual single letter names (there are, presumably, many earlier commits not shown here):

```
          C--D   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B
         \
          E--F   <-- other
```

or another graph with just four commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- other
```

Remember also that in a Git commit graph, commits—the items represented here by single uppercase letters, but in reality they have big ugly hash IDs as their real names—always point *backwards*, to their parent commits.  That is, the connecting lines between commits are really arrows: `A ← B`, and they always point from later commits (children) to earlier commits (the child's parent).

For merge purposes, what we do is start at both of the specific commits—`D` and `F` in the first graph, and `H` and `J` in the second; typically these are *branch tip* commits—and we follow these backwards arrows from the commits to their parents.  We do this "simultaneously" along all possible paths until we find some commit that is *reachable* from both of our branch tip commits.

It's easy to see, from these graphs, that when we start from `D` and `F` and work backwards, the "nearest", i.e., best, commit that's on *both* branches is `B`.  This commit is two steps back from each tip.  Likewise, when we start from `H` and `J`, the best commit that's on both branches is in fact commit `H` itself: that's *no* steps back from `H`, and two steps back from `J`.

Hence the merge base is sometimes a commit that comes before either tip, but occasionally, the merge base is the current commit.

(It's even possible to ask Git to merge something that's already merged, as occurs in this graph:

```
...--K--L   <-- other
         \
          M   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

In this case, if you ask Git to `git merge other`, Git will say that there is nothing to merge.  Nothing you do will convince Git to do anything at this point, so that's not really an interesting case for us.)

#### A fast-forward instead of a merge

Now, whenever the merge base of `HEAD` and `<other>` is `HEAD` itself, that's a case when it's possible to do a fast-forward operation, *instead* of merging.  In this particular case, what Git will do is "slide the branch name forward" (fast, across all the intermediate commits, and in the opposite direction of the arrows):

```
...--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- other
```

becomes:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- branch (HEAD), other
```

When Git does this, all it has to do is check out commit `J`.  There's no actual *merge* required; there is no special work to do, and there is no need to make a new merge commit.  Git can just slide the name forward and check out the other commit.

#### A true merge

On the other hand, when `HEAD` points to some commit `D` and `other` points to some commit `F` where it's *not* possible to just "slide forward", as in:

```
          C--D   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--A--B
         \
          E--F   <-- other
```

Git must do some real work.  It has to find out what *we* changed, in our commits `C--D`, as compared to what's in the merge base `B`.  Then it has to find out what *they* changed, in *their* commits `E--F`, as compared to what's in the merge base `B`.  Git, in effect, runs two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames B D   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames B F   # what they changed
```

Git then has to *combine* these changes: starting from whatever is in commit `B`, make *both* sets of changes, being sure to take only one copy if we both did "the same thing" (whatever that means).  Having combined the changes—successfully (or at least Git thinks it succeeded)—Git will then make a *new* commit from the result, and add it to our branch (conveniently named `branch`):

```
          C--D---N   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /      /
...--A--B      /
         \    /
          E--F   <-- other
```

This new commit `N` is a *merge commit:* it has two parents instead of one.  It records the fact that Git has merged commits `D` and `F`, by having `D` as its first parent and `F` as its second parent.  The *snapshot* for this commit is Git's combination of both sets of changes.

(If the merge *fails*, Git simply stops at this point with a failure message, leaving a mess in the index/staging-area and work-tree.  It's then your job to clean up the mess and finish the merge, or run `git merge --abort` to tell Git that this was a bad idea and it should go back to the saved state from before even attempting the merge.)

#### You are getting true merges

We know from your `git log` output that you are getting true merges.  Therefore, we must be hitting cases that look like `D`-vs-`F`.  But you're not making your own commits by doing work and running `git commit`, so, how is it that you have commits on your branch that, after `git fetch`ing from Repo-A, they *don't* have on *their* branch?

#### It could be from `git reset`...

One way you could be getting this is if you do `git reset`.  What `git reset` does is complicated, and I'll skip a huge amount of details that are critical to using it correctly, and just note that along with everything else `git reset` does, it *can* re-point your current branch name—the one to which your `HEAD` is attached—to *any* of your existing commits.  For instance, if you have this graph:

```
          T--U   <-- origin/abc
         /
...--P--Q--R--S   <-- xyzzy (HEAD), origin/xyzzy
```

you can direct your own `xyzzy` to point instead to commit `T` or commit `U`, without changing anything else in the graph:

```
          T--U   <-- xyzzy (HEAD), origin/abc
         /
...--P--Q--R--S   <-- origin/xyzzy
```

If, at this point, you direct your Git to merge your current branch `xyzzy` with your `origin/xyzzy`—your Git's memory of where `xyzzy` was on `origin` the last time your Git checked in with `origin` and found that—well, now your Git will have to make a new merge commit, to combine the changes in `U` and `S` since merge-base `Q`.

#### But it could also be from an upstream history rewrite

Suppose, though, that you're *not* doing this kind of `git reset`.  Suppose you're just trying to follow along with what someone else is doing.  You run `git fetch origin`, in your Repo-B, to have your Git call up their Git and get their commits and branches.  Your Git starts out with just these two commits, which you got from them:

```
A--B   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Your Git picks up their new commit `C`:

```
A--B   <-- master (HEAD)
    \
     C   <-- origin/master
```

and you have your Git do a normal fast-forward, giving you:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Now, a few seconds (or hours or days) later, you run this thing again, and they've decided that their commit `C` was a terrible awful no-good thing and they've *ditched* it, in favor of a shiny new better commit `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
    \
     D   <-- origin/master
```

Well, your Git will now clearly have to *merge* your changes, the stuff you wrote that they didn't, in commit `C`, with *their* changes, the stuff they wrote that you didn't, in commit `D`:

```
A--B--C---E   <-- master (HEAD)
       \ /
        D   <-- origin/master
```

This is the danger of an upstream history rewrite: Git thinks commit `C` is *your* work that you intend to *keep*.  Git is using a very simple rule to make this decision: commit `C` is on your `master` and not—well, not any more!—on their `origin/master`, so `C` *must* be yours.

#### Rebase and fork-point

Since Git version 2.0, `git` has acquired the ability to discover, in some (but not all) cases, exactly this kind of upstream history rewrite, and to recover from it.  As we just saw, the problem with commit `C` in our example is that Git thinks `C` is our own.  But clearly it *wasn't* ours, because it *was* on `origin/master` at some point.  It isn't *now*, after the `git fetch` updated our `origin/master`, but it *was*.  If only Git remembered what the *previous* value of `origin/master` was.

Well, in fact, Git *does* remember the previous value, in a *reflog*.  Our own `origin/master` has a reflog (as long as reflogs are enabled), and the reflog remembers the previous value, for a while anyway.  Git could look in our `origin/master` reflog and discover that `C` came from `origin` and is now gone from `origin`.

Git calls doing this kind of thing—looking for commits that were ripped out of an upstream branch—finding a *fork point*, and since Git version 2.0, `git merge-base --fork-point` will do that.  The `git rebase` command will find the fork-point and automatically throw commit `C` out when we run:

```
git rebase --fork-point origin/master
```

or more simply, just:

```
git rebase
```

(as long as we have set `origin/master` as the *upstream* setting of the current branch `master`).

If you configure `git pull` to use rebasing, instead of merging, you will get this behavior automatically.  In fact, you don't even have to have Git version 2.0 or later, as this special fork-point computation was first done as an experiment in 1.5 or 1.6 or so, specifically in `git pull --rebase` (regular `git rebase`, and `git merge`, did not support `--fork-point`).  (Git versions 1.9 and up have the fork-point option, but it's easier to remember as a 2.x feature.)

#### Mirroring options

I mentioned that you can make a mirror or otherwise "perfect copy".  A mirror—more specifically a fetch mirror—is a *bare* clone, created with `git clone --mirror`.  Since it *is* a bare clone it has no work-tree and you cannot use it directly.  You can, however, check out into a temporarily-assigned work-tree:

```
git clone --mirror <url>
cd <repository>
mkdir /some/path
git checkout --work-tree=/some/path branch
```

This mirror clone, when you run `git fetch`, will have its branch names forcibly updated to match the upstream repository.  Since it has no work-tree of its own there are no files to update, but you can continue to check out some specific branch into some specific work-tree.

The subtlety here is that this mirror clone still has one `HEAD` and one index, and that one `HEAD` and index will be used during `git checkout`.  The `HEAD` will be attached (or detached if appropriate) to the branch (or from the commit) you check out, and the index will be used to index / cache the temporarily-assigned work-tree.

Alternatively, you can create a normal clone, but always use `git checkout --detach` to make sure that you never create any of your own branches, or check out by remote-tracking names:

```
git clone <url>
cd <repository>
git checkout origin/branch
git branch -D master  # discard local branch name
```

You can now just run `git fetch` followed by `git checkout origin/branch` and never have to worry about the commits that you don't make on the branches you don't have.

Comment: Thanks. Long answer (gonna read through everything later), but the important takeaway for me was that `git pull` would create these merges in some cases. I will look into ways to avoid `git pull` in any circumstance, since I don't think I will be able to prevent the situations that causes a merge.

Answer (score 0):

> How is this possible?

You have the answer in your history, check the parents of the merge.

To see which commits you have locally when you see message "Your branch is ahead of..." you can use command:

```
git log @{u}..
```